# query sorting selections based on number of classes matched

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to sort results from the **dropdown menu** `checkbox` selections by the results that have the most matching classes. I think I can use `.length()` I'm just not sure of the context. 

Here is the code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mstiller/N5SwW/)

Comment: Here's what I would do: Clear all `li`'s "weight" attribute. For each one checked, increment the `li`'s weight. Afterwards, sort the `ul` based on weight.

Comment: I still ended up using the length, but clearing the div worked. Thank you for the clue, it was much appreciated :)